# Can we use Google Script to import txt file and replace the targeted sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, import, automation, txt

My job requires updating data daily and presenting it on Google Data Studio. The input data will be refreshing daily and formatted as txt files (16 files to be exact). Then I have to import those files manually to multiple worksheets by replacing the current sheets. And the problem is it takes a lot of time and I need to use something automated to optimize our workloads by using Script. Can anybody help me with this problem and show me how to build that Script for all the files? Thank you guys a lot and hope u have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

Daniel, there is a lack of informations. Howerver, to upload a txt file with tabulations, you can use (and adapt for you) this script :

```
function convert_txt_gsheets(){
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file.txt').next();
  var body = file.getBlob().getDataAsString().split(/\n/);
  var result = body.map( r => r.split(/\t/));
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0].getRange(1,1,result.length,result[0].length).setValues(result);
  return;
}
```